# How to add individual column search with serverside datatable using ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I have tried to add individual column search in the server side datatable but its not working.

```
  // Apply the filter
    $("#empTable tfoot input").on( 'keyup change', function () { alert('test');
        tables
            .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
```

I need the solution for this how to achieve in the datatable

Comment: This is not enough to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please try to add a minimum reproducible steps.

Answer (score 0):

assume you will filter column name, add this input in top column name

```
<input type="text" class="name_filter reload_datatable">
```

change your ajax datatable to this

```
var table = $(".table").DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": "urlajax",
    "dataType": "json",
    "type": "post",
    "data": function(d) {
      d.name= $('.name_filter').val()
    }
  }
}
```

create function on change like this

```
$(".reload_datatable").change(function(){
  table.ajax.reload();
});
```

and get data in ajax php with

```
$_POST['name']
```